AIC from sarima vs arima functions in R
I am doing a report of time series, and while analyzing the time series in R, I noticed the using the sarima function
yh_sarima1<-sarima(train_yh, p = 1, d = 1, q = 2, P = 0, D = 1, Q = 2, S = 12)
I got an aic of 22 , while using the equivalent arima function
yh_arima1 <- arima(train_yh, order = c(1, 1, 2), seasonal = list(order = c(0, 1, 2), period = 12))
I got an AIC of over 4100, which leads to the question why? And also while comparing different models to include in the report to justify the use of seasonality or not, how exactly I interpret AIC or the overall metrics to justify a model is better than the other, to forecast afterward, considering of course the residuals are somewhat similar?

Maybe one is per-observation while the other is the usual one? If you multiply 22 by your sample size, do you get roughly 4100? Only roughly, because the likelihood may not be calculated on the entire sample but instead by discarding some initial points. But there are other things that can differ, like omitting constants from the likelihood in one but not the other function...

sarima is not part of base R. Please explain what packages you are using. Note that different packages calculate AIC differently. See https://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/lm_aic.html
